# MongoClient not found in PHP on Mac OSX using brew

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, homebrew

I am trying to setup mongodb + php mongo driver [using homebrew](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php) 
I am trying to setup a [composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/perftools/xhgui) which requires mongodb.

The extension seems to be installed, as it appear in both cli and web version as below. But when I hit the webroot I get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in
>   /Users/sakhunzai/Sites/xhgui/public/src/Xhgui/ServiceContainer.php on
>   line 77

I am able to connect to mongodb and create a database etc. So mongodb is running fine. But It seems there is issue with php extension. To setup [xhgui](https://packagist.org/packages/perftools/xhgui) I have brewed as follow:

```
brew tap tideways/homebrew-profiler
brew install php56-tideways
brew install mongodb php56-mongodb
```

MongoDB

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
```

Extension

```
php -i|grep mongo
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
mongodb support => enabled
mongodb version => 1.1.6
mongodb stability => stable
libmongoc version => 1.3.5
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

[image]

```
cat /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two kinds of drivers available at pecl

[image]

you need to install the mongoDB database driver to access mongoClient

use the following command to install the mongo

```
brew install php56-mongo
```

as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx)

You will get something like this in your phpinfo();

[image]

I hope this helps. Thanks,

Comment: excellent,thanks . I skipped that extension given the warning `This extension is deprecated.`

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helps.

Comment: Thanks for this – i was getting a similar error because it couldn't find something called MongoCursor. I must say it seems deliberately designed to confuse: two php extensions named "mongo database driver for php" and "mongo database database driver", wtf?